# Templated check for the existence of a class member function template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, sfinae

Can someone explain to me how can I check for existence of a class member function template specializations with C++17? I have tried solution from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30848101) and it works fine for normal functions:

```
template<typename, template<typename> class, typename = void_t<>>
struct detect : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, template<typename> class Op>
struct detect<T, Op, void_t<Op<T>>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
using simple_func_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().SimpleFunc());

template<typename T>
using has_simple_func = detect<T, simple_func_t>;

class Test
{
public:
    int SimpleFunc()
    {
        cout << "SimpleFunc\n";
        return 0;
    }
};

void Foo()
{
    if constexpr (has_simple_func<Test>())
    {
        Test test;
        test.SimpleFunc();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I can not make it work for specialized member functions. I have tried that:

```
template<typename, template<typename> class, typename = void_t<>>
struct detect_ver : std::false_type {};

template<typename T, template<typename> class Op>
struct detect_ver<T, Op, void_t<Op<T>>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T, int version>
using template_func_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().TemplateFunc<version>());

template<typename T, int version>
using has_template_func = detect_ver<T, template_func_t<T, version>>;

class Test
{
public:
    template<int version>
    int TemplateFunc();

    template<>
    int TemplateFunc<1>()
    {
        cout << "TemplateFunc1\n";
        return 1;
    }
};

void Foo()
{
    if constexpr (has_template_func<Test, 1>())
    {
        Test test;
        test.TemplateFunc<1>();
    }
}
```

But I keep getting strange compile errors like this:
`error C2760:  syntax error: unexpected token ')', expected 'expression'`
for line:
`using template_func_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().TemplateFunc<version>());`

UPDATE:
I have tried solution provided by jarod. It compiles, but detect_ver deducted as false_type. I do use MSVC.

Comment: `detect_ver` expects a template template, which `template_func_t<T, version>` is not.

Comment: There are no templated functions in C++, there are function templates.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your traits to match `detect_ver` parameters:

```
template<int version>
struct template_func_t
{
    template<typename T>
    using type = decltype(std::declval<T>().template TemplateFunc<version>());
};

template<typename T, int version>
using has_template_func = detect_ver<T, template_func_t<version>::template type>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hEWh34raP)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, although @Jarod's answer solves the syntax errors, this still doesn't work, because `if constexpr (has_template_func<Test, N>())` [always returns `true`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mdH307DaOxBQAYyv), regardless of the value of `N`.

To see why this is so, consider the following simplified code:

```
class Test
{
public:
    template<int version>
    int TemplateFunc();
};

int main ()
{
    Test test;
    test.TemplateFunc<1>();
}
```

This compiles but does not link (`undefined reference to int Test::TemplateFunc<1>()`).

This is because this:

```
template<int version>
int TemplateFunc();
```

acts as a forward declaration of `TemplateFunc` (in fact, it *is* a forward declaration of `TemplateFunc`), and that is enough to compile the code.

So, **tl;dr**, there's no way to check for the existence of a particular template specialisation, period.

OP: I'm not sure why you're always getting `std::false_type`.  That's not what I see with [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6PdoY9MU9IGyiXVO) or [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mdH307DaOxBQAYyv).